# How to assert specific part of Response Value using "Equals" assertion in SoapUI NG Pro?

Tags: angularjs, rest, unit-testing, testing, soapui

These are steps I followed to stuck my work.

1. Created a sample project in SoapUI NG Pro
2. Generated a test suite for the service belongs to webservice
3. Added "Equals" assertion for the test step

While configuring with "Equals" assertion, I set "Target" as "Text" and "Target Text" is **"THE BARTELL DRUG CO"** which is part of whole response of the web service.

But assertion is showing in "RED" color which seems it is "FAILED". Could anyone tell me how we can assert the response value using "Equals" assertion?

Thanks
Karunagara Pandi

Answer (score 0):

The **Equals** assertion checks that the entire response is equal to the value entered in the assertion. It is useful if you want to match the entire response.

I would suggest to use either the **Contains** assertion or **XPath Match** assertion.

The **Contains** assertion check that the response contains the value entered in the assertion. Use this if you are looking for the occurrence of a text.

The **XPath Match** assertion checks that a specific node in the returned XML has a specific value. If it is XML you get in your response I would use this one in most of the cases.

Comment: thank you jonsson for you helpful reply. I thought it will also check part of the response value.